# Zooming on foreign object in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I zoom a foreign object?

Code:

```
 var menu = svgContainer.append('foreignObject').attr('width', 480).attr('height', 500);


var result = d3.select('foreignObject').html('<div id="divDT1" class="dataModelTable selected"><div class="dataTableName"> Skill </div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes </div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1" style="display: block;"><ul><li class="columnsList">SkillDisplayName </li><li class="columnsList">skillName </li><li class="columnsList">idSkill </li><li class="columnsList">skillDesxription </li></ul></div></div></div>')
            .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () 
           {
             result.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
           }));
```

Tried with zoom function but not working

Comment: @Robert Longson when I try to zoom with mousewheel its not zooming in

Comment: @Robert Longson I figured it out. When I remove the css styles(external style sheet) the zoom is working else its not. but ofcourse without styles its looking ugly. How do I retain zoom functionality with styles

Comment: @RobertLongson Here is the css: `.dataTableName{background-color:#f9f9f9; color:#000000; padding:5px 10px; border-radius:5px  5px 0 0; border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;}`

Comment: Still works for me. You really need to work out what the problem is.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am on it! Thank you anyway

Comment: I encoutered the same problem. @Satyadev is there any solution?

Comment: @thinkh I started using other library for SVG's called JointJs which solved all my issues. Changing libraries may not be a solution for you

Comment: @Satyadev Changing the library is not an option. However, thanks for the reference to JointJs. I will have a look.